How do I install the tagalong plugin with vim-plug?
I am unsure if I followed the steps correctly when trying to install the plugin tagalong.
The problem is its functionality is not working after I installed it. Here are the steps I took.

Per https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug
I installed vim-plug by copy-pasting the following commands in windows powershell
iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim |`
 ni $HOME/vimfiles/autoload/plug.vim -Force


I wrote this in my .vimrc file located in C:\Users\myname\.vimrc
call plug#begin()
Plug 'AndrewRadev/tagalong.vim'   
call plug#end()


I saved and closed the .vimrc file and opened a new one in order to run
:PlugInstall



After the tagalong plugin was installed I opened a new file to start trying out the plugin. I expected HTML opening/closing tags to match the other if I edited them, but this isn't happening. Any idea what is going wrong?

"Any idea what is going wrong?" Yes. You are asking here instead of using the project's issue tracker.

Check the paths returned by :set runtimepath? if any of them contains your plugin. If yes, it's properly installed and the error is inside the plugin.

@Friedrich thanks! I'll go check their github and ask follow up questions there.
